# Reactivity with rubbing alcohol and PVC

Tags: organic-chemistry

Rubbing alcohol seems to make polyvinyl plastic more sticky; i.e. if I clean a tube connector with rubbing alcohol first and then insert it into the plastic tube, it supposedly secures the seal significantly better than attaching the connector without the rubbing alcohol. Why might that be chemically speaking?

Comment: It could be just that you clean plasticizers off of surface. Just guessing, but diffusion of plasticizers from PVC is quite quick